# How to create a custom role in Azure, so that another user is able to only view the list of files in a blob container but not its contents(RBAC)

Tags: azure, role-based-access-control

How to create a custom role in Azure using Access Control(IAM), so that another user is able to view the list of files in a blob container but not its contents. Also, the user should not be able to make any changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Storage restrict access one container only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185000/azure-storage-restrict-access-one-container-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create a custom role in Azure using Access Control(IAM), so
>   that another user is able to view the list of files in a blob
>   container but not its contents. Also, the user should not be able to
>   make any changes.

I don't think it is possible to do so with RBAC roles.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#permissions-for-calling-blob-and-queue-data-operations), both `List Blobs` and `Get Blob` operation require `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read (scoped to the blob container)` permission thus if a user is in a role that has this permission, then that user will be able to perform both operations.

However you can achieve this using [`Shared Access Signature (SAS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas). If you create a SAS on a blob container with just `list` permissions, using that SAS URL a user will only be able to list blobs in a blob container and nothing else.