# Azure Storage restrict access one container only

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

This is my situation: Two groups in Azure AD.
Group 1 can access only container1, but not container2
Group 2 can access only container2, but not container1

To achieve this I have given IAM Role Permission on each container accordingly (assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor Role to group).

Code Sample I used: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-azure-ad-msal

But to upload/download any file on container I have to assign role of Storage Blob Data Contributor on Storage Account as well. If I give Storage Blob Data Contributor on Storage Account then that Group users can add files to any container.

So is there any way to achieve like,
Group 1 can access only container1, but not container2
Group 2 can access only container2, but not container1

Comment: Why is it necessary to also assign the Storage Data Blob Reader to the Storage Account itself? I have tried to create a Blob Container and assigned a test user Storage Data Blob Reader to this container. In the blob container I have uploaded a test file. When I give the URL to this test file, the test user gets a Resource Not Found when trying to download the file in a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denying group to a container is [not supported yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/31622/restrict-access-to-a-specific-container-in-a-azure.html). As given in the image taken from IAM blade: "At this time, the only way you can add your own deny assignments is by using Azure Blueprints."
Denying access to users is quite a process. So it is best if you create two storage accounts and manage the access at storage account level instead of Container. This is not for group but for a single user in group. [image]

Comment: Is it possible to only give access to one container by using a custom role?

Comment: When will this rule kick in? How will you add access to storage account ?

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is assign 'Reader' access to the storage account, then 'Storage Blob Data Reader' for that same user/group, BUT provide a condition to only allow them access to containers of a specific name. In my example below I called the container "test-access-medata"

[image]

Comment: I tried multiple ways of assigning container-only access and your approach is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should be flagged as an answer to this question, thanks a lot!